# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, json, django, ajax, e-commerce

i'm making a django ecommerce site from a this [youtube ecommerce tutorial](https://youtu.be/VOwfGW-ZTIY).i have created a function for the delete from cart but when i press the delete button, i get this message

> TypeError at /cart/delete/ int() argument must be a string, a
> bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'

here is the function

```
def cart_delete(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        product_id = int(request.POST.get('productid'))
        cart.delete(product=product_id)
        response = JsonResponse({'success':True})
        return response

> TypeError at /cart/delete/ int() argument must be a string, a
> bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType' Request
> Method:   POST Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/delete/ Django
> Version:  3.2.8 Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:   int()
> argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not
> 'NoneType' Exception
> Location: C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ecommerce\cart\views.py, line 30, in
> cart_delete Python
> Executable:   C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ecommerce\venv\scripts\python.exe
> Python Version:   3.10.0
```

delete function

```
def delete(self, product):
        product_id = str(product) 
         
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            
        self.session.modified = True
```

my ajax script

```
<script>
        $(document).on('click', '#delete-button', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log($('#select option:selected').text())
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'{% url "cart:cart_delete" %}',
                data:{
                    productid: $('#add-button').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:"{{csrf_token}}",
                    productqty: $('#select option:selected').text(),
                    action: 'post'
                },
                success: function (json){
                     
                },
                error: function (xhr, errmsg, err){}
            })
        })
        
      
    </script>
```

some please help.

Comment: you're calling the delete function with NoneType varaible. can you just debug what are you setting in the function params

Answer (score 1):

Your `productid` in `request.POST` are empty. Check in your browser console the value with `$('#add-button').val()`.

You can check if exsist with the `in` operator.

```py
if productid in request.POST:
    product_id = int(request.POST.get('productid'))
    cart.delete(product=product_id)
    response = JsonResponse({'success':True})
else :
    response = JsonResponse({'success': False})
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Tonio said in his answer the value of the #add-button was empty

But if you also came from the Youtube tutorial the issue was solved later on the in the video.